# JdbcSQLNonTransientException when using h2 with file db

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I'm following [this Spring Boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) but I wanted to use a file instead of the in-memory database, so I just added the following line to my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/somefile
```

Everything seems to work correctly, I can create, delete, update and read objects, but I noticed that in the trace.db file there were a buch of the following exception:

```
2023-10-01 17:02:46 jdbc[3]: exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: L'objet est déjà fermé
The object is already closed [90007-214]
```